# Regex to match the content of img src within div

Tags: regex

I m new on this field so i don't have much idea about `regex`. My problem is like this
I have a `"div"` within it their is a `"href"` attribute and finally their is `"img"`. I want a `regex` to match the `"img"` source content by which i can get the data of that content if the `url` of that particular content matches.

```
<div class="test_list3">
   <a href="/photo/tst_t_45288/6782/12/1/">`<img  src="http://example.com/1700/tst_t_45288/m2/tst_t_45288_1.jpg" title="tst-t  1" alt="tst-t 1" /></a><br /><a href="http://example.com/1700/tst_t_45288/tst_t_45288_1.jpg"  target="_blank">jpg file</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use an XML parser. HTML is not a regular language and so regex should not be used with it.

Comment: @MillieSmith - on the other hand, HTML (in most of its forms) isn't XML so an XML parser may also choke on it. An HTML parser, on the other hand, would be quite suitable.

Comment: In what context are you gonning to execute your regex on the html? I mean is it a java program? or what?

Comment: Hm. Thanks for pointing that out @Damien_The_Unbeliever. For some reason I thought HTML was a subset

Comment: @MillieSmith - no, HTML has void elements (e.g. `<br>` and `<link>`) which shouldn't, properly, have closing tags.

Comment: why `regexp`???? why not `xpath'? could give the full html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a regex is your *last choice*, you can go with this:

```
(?s)<div[^>]*>.*<img.*src=\"([^"]+)\".*<\/div>
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jZ8yO4)

***Explanation***

- because you have multiple lines `s` flag needed to make `dot` matches newlines.
- then checking for opening `div` tag and all its attributes by  `<div[^>]*>`

  - `[^>]*` zero or more characters but not `>`
- then we should match all other things till we reach to opening `img` tag by `.*`
- after that we should go through possibly attributes or spaces before `src` attribute here `<img.*src`
- then capturing all characters except `"` in `src` : `src=\"([^"]+)`
- and finally escape all things till first occurrence of closing `div` tag happens

Answer (score 0):

I think I cannot do this by only one reg exp

1.Using `<div[^>]*>[^<>]*(((?'Open'<div[^>]*>)[^<>]*)+((?'-Open'</div>)[^<>]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))</div>` get the content between two div tags.

2.Using other reg exp matchs the matching string in step1 and get the content between the img tags.